# updating too much notifications cause lag, how to improve it?

Tags: java, android, notifications, progress-bar

I am downloading multiple files in parallel (more than **10**) using Async task (The code is in a different .java file than the Main.java).
I spawn many Async task and each task will call onProgress about every 2 seconds
in the Async task onProgress method, it will update a text and progress bar in the notification bar

```
Main.notification.contentView.setProgressBar(R.id.status_progress, 100, percentCompleted, false); // percentCompleted is calculated
Main.notification.contentView.setTextViewText(R.id.status_text, title);
Main.nm.notify(value, Main.notification);
```

Note that I declare and initialize the "notification" and "nm" in Main.java as public static. (so I can easily call them in my async task which is in another .java file)

```
public static Notification notification;
public static NotificationManager nm;
```

When I am downloading about **5** files in parallel, it is still working fine (no obvious lag).
But when I am downloading more than **10** files in parallel, the notification bar become very lag.
It even crashed when when I am downloading **20** files in parallel with error "unfortunately system ui has stopped", and my notification bar disappear totally (must reboot phone).

What is the better way of updating multiple notification like this, but with no lag?

Please note that the lag is not caused by the download in the Async task. I have tried the download without showing notification in notification bar, and it has no lag at all. (Galaxy S3 Quad Cores Exynos)

[image]

Comment: Well, you could just "don't" fill the whole notification bar with your downloads but instead set a max number. For example if more than 5 downloads, only one notification showing overall-progress and how many are active/finished, onClick brings the user to an activity/fragment/something displaying all downloads and their states? I don't think anyone would want to have more than 5 or 10 notifications at the same time.

Comment: yea, it could be an good solution too. But I prefer to solve it with simpler solution. If it is really impossible for the notification bar to not lag with multiple notifications, then I will use your suggestion. Thanks!

Comment: @tcboy88 this answer here worked for me :  [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28336694/9005383)

Answer (score 0):

Be aware that if you call your AsyncTasks like: `as.execute();`, they are not running in parallel. For that you would need to: `as.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR))`

Comment: All of my download tasks are running with task.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);

Comment: That was the easy answer, fix it setting a max of notifications or keep thinking and give us the answer!!! :)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't make just one notification with information about all the downloads, like total progress.

Clicking the multiple downloads notification shows a new `Activity` showing more detailed information about the individual downloads.

I personally think users don't like so many notifications and rater see it merged in to one.

Comment: Because all the progress (percentage) are in different Async Task. I will need some mechanism to combine all of them into a total progress (maybe using a global variable or something). But I prefer a simpler method, without need to show a new Activity. Thanks!

Comment: I personally still would try to make a good user experience, you could also choose to don't show any progress at all, and just tell the user "17 downloads active". I believe showing so much notifications could be really annoying to users. But if really not possible, try making use of Thread executors.