# Why NotificationManager works so slow during the update progress?

Tags: android, android-notifications

I publish file upload progress via NotificationManager, but while updating its progress UI freezes.

I use NotificationCompat.Builder, which cached in the class field. So progress publishing is a very simple:

```
manager.notify(id, uploader.
    setProgress(MAX_PROGRESS, (int) (progress * 100), false).
    build()
);
```

Update progress is guaranteed to execute from the main thread(wrapped in Handler decorator).

```
this.request.setCallback(new UploaderDecorator(this.request.getCallback()));
```

The very publication of progress is as follows:

```
long total = file.length();
long uploaded = 0;
int bytesRead = input.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
while (bytesRead > 0) {
    output.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
    uploaded += bytesRead;
    callback.onUploadProgress(activeFile, ((float) uploaded / total));
    bytesRead = input.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
}
```

So why it's works so slow?

Comment: "Update progress is guaranteed to execute from the main thread(wrapped in Handler decorator)" -- you do not need to update a `Notification` from the main application thread. In fact, that may be contributing to your problem.

Comment: @CommonsWare Removed decorator, compared id process, as they are different, but the problem remained.
The problem in the notification bar, my app works with same speed.

Comment: Maybe it's because the notifications are sent too often?

Comment: Most download progress bars that I see in notifications don't appear to update all that often -- maybe once every few seconds. It's certainly possible that you're flooding the `NotificationManager`, depending upon how big `bufferSize` is.

Comment: @CommonsWare  bufferSize is 1024. I should increase him? To what value?

Comment: Well, I'd certainly use a larger buffer, regardless of the `Notification` issue, just for performance. 8-16K at a minimum.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is a common behavior. You shouldn't flood the NotificationManager with frequent updates. You should decide an interval to update, like twice every second.

For example,

```
long startTime;
long elapsedTime = 0L;

if (elapsedTime > 500) {
    new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            mBuilder.setProgress(100, (int) newValue, false);
            mNotifyManager.notify(notificationID, mBuilder.build());

            startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            elapsedTime = 0;
        }
    });

    Log.d("Andrognito", newValue + "Progress");
}
else
    elapsedTime = new Date().getTime() - startTime;
```

This works perfectly for me and doesn't freeze the notifications too.

Comment: What is minimal interval I can put, do you know?

Comment: Works perfectly even for multiple notifications ! thanks